# Error connecting to Oracle database (ORA-12560)

Tags: vb.net, oracle

I'm hitting the error mentioned in the Title when attempting to connect to the database in the VB.net application I'm developing. I know it's not the listener or any service issue, as I'm able to connect to the same database, with the same credentials in a different application I developed (I ran that application after failing to connect with the one I'm developing, so it's not the Windows Event log).

Both use an `Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleConnection` to reference an existing ODBC connection. The connections are created and opened in slightly different ways so I figure it's something in my VB code that's causing the issue, but I can't for the life of me think of what it might be.

The non-functional code:

```vb
Public Function EstablishCon(ByVal odbc As String, 
        ByVal uname As String, 
        ByVal pass As String) As Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleConnection
    '
    Dim constr As String
    Dim scon As Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleConnection = Nothing

    Try
        constr = "Data Source=" & odbc & ";User Id=" & uname & ";Password=" & pass & ";"
        scon = New Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleConnection(constr)
        scon.Open()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("Encountered an error while creating the Oracle connection string and opening the connection. This will cause the application to be unable to access any data." _
            & " As such the application will close following the closure of this error message." & Chr(10) & Chr(10) & "Error Details: " & ex.Message, vbOKOnly, _
            "Critical Error: Failed to the Oracle Database")
        scon.ConnectionString = Nothing
    End Try

    Return scon
End Function
```

Whereas my working code looks like:

```vb
Private Sub MainWin_Shown(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Shown
    '
    'Dim scmd As New SqlClient.SqlCommand
    Dim QTxt As String = ""
    Dim ConStr As String = "Data Source=existing ODBC connection name;User Id=user_name;Password=pass;"
    Dim scon As New Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleConnection(ConStr)
    Dim d As New DataStore
    Dim scmd As New Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleCommand
    Dim odr As Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleDataReader

    'Setup the datatable in d
    Try
        d.DT.Columns.Add("App_Type")
        d.DT.Columns("App_Type").DataType = GetType(String)
        d.DT.Columns.Add("CPU_Seconds")
        d.DT.Columns("CPU_Seconds").DataType = GetType(Double)
        'd.DT.Columns.Add("Pct_Of_CPU")
        'd.DT.Columns("Pct_Of_CPU").DataType = GetType(Double)
        d.DT.Columns.Add("RunDate")
        d.DT.Columns("RunDate").DataType = GetType(Date)
    Catch ex As Exception
        Me.Errors.Text = "Encountered an error setting up the data table that will receive the query data. Details: " & ex.Message
        d = Nothing
        scon = Nothing
        scmd = Nothing
        ConStr = Nothing
        QTxt = Nothing
        odr = Nothing
        Exit Sub
    End Try


    Me.Status.Text = Now() & " - Building the SQL executor"
    Me.Refresh()
    'Build the query executor
    Try
        scmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
        scmd.Connection = scon

        'Capture the query text
        QTxt = 'Some text that makes a valid query 

        scmd.CommandText = QTxt
    Catch ex As Exception
        Me.Errors.Text = "An error occurred while building the SQL Executor. Details: " & ex.Message & Chr(10) & Chr(10) & Me.Errors.Text
        d = Nothing
        scon = Nothing
        scmd = Nothing
        ConStr = Nothing
        QTxt = Nothing
        odr = Nothing
        Exit Sub
    End Try

    Me.ProgBar.Step = 5
    Me.ProgBar.PerformStep()
    Me.Status.Text = Now() & " - Connecting to the database" & Chr(10) & Me.Status.Text
    Me.Refresh()
    Try
        'Open the connection
        scon.Open()
    Catch ex As Exception
        Me.Errors.Text = "An error occurred while opening the SQL connection. Details: " & ex.Message & Chr(10) & Chr(10) & Me.Errors.Text
        d = Nothing
        scon.Close()
        scon = Nothing
        scmd = Nothing
        ConStr = Nothing
        QTxt = Nothing
        odr = Nothing
        Exit Sub
    End Try

   'Some more stuff that's not relevant
End Sub
```

Sorry for the messy formatting, I spent 15 minutes trying to keep the two blocks of code separate, but StackOverflow just wasn't having it.

So the only real difference between the two is that one filled in the connection string when declaring the Connection variable, and the other does so later and in a separate function. The function aspect doesn't appear to factor as the error is thrown and caught inside the function. I

Comment: I doubt that your Data source is `existing ODBC connection name`. What is your real string (both cases)?

Answer (score 0):

So the problem was how I was invoking the form that calls for the function. I had use `.Show` rather than `.ShowDialog`.

This resulted in the form variables (which hold the values that get passed in as  `odbc`, `uname`, & `pass`) being cleared prior to hitting the `Shown` event (where the connection function is invoked).